# Visualization of TLC plates

Tags: organic-chemistry, chromatography

I'd like to know what exactly happens when various agents are used after developing a TLC plate, during the visualization phase, of sugars with anisaldehyde for example.

I know that those compounds are used in order to make invisible stains, visible. Also, sometimes, application of heat is necessary, I reckon so as to speed the "colouring process". However, I'd like to learn what kind of reactions take place or what kind of products are there formed, since I was not able to reach a conclusion after my research.

Comment: Google is your friend! Start here https://www.silicycle.com/faq/thin-layer-chromatography/stains-for-tlc-plates then look up each named stain reagent

Comment: I've found similar charts but they don't describe what exactly happens reaction-wise. The only webiste I've found that partially describes the occuring reactions is this one: http://www.reachdevices.com/TLC_stains.html However, even here, some reactions are missing or are simple theories, yet to be corroborated.